# React Native : Implement TabBarIOS to Navigation Experimental

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uinavigationbar, redux, react-redux

I found this great example on React Native Navigation Experimental :
https://github.com/jlyman/RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example

This is exactly what i was looking for. It has navigation bar and title, and navigation works fine. But it doesn't have TabBarIOS implemented.

Also i found this one by Nader Dabit, :
https://github.com/dabit3/react-native-navigator-experimental-redux/tree/part3-tabs

This is also great, it has TabBarIOS in this example, but it doesn't have Navigation Header. and when i was running it, it some times gives error due to duplicate same key declaration.

Navigation on first one, works better. i tried to implement tabbarios according to this tutorial :
https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-experimental-part-3-adding-tabs-28a2c57356b6#.r950tldx6

But my try was not successful. i tried to combine two reducers but it didn't work.

How can i do that properly? I'm trying to add TabBarIOS to first example. That gonna be a great starter app for react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created simple example to show [Composite Navigation With TabBar](https://github.com/nak1b/react-native-composite-navigation) using Navigation Experimental and redux. It works with both android and iOS. I have used custom TabBar component but it can be easily replaced with native TabBarIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found another example here :
http://blog.thebakery.io/react-native-experimental-navigation-with-redux/

Which has TabBarIOS, Navigation Header, and everything i was looking for.

Hope that will help others who search for samething :)